# Bind string property to dynamically filled dropdownlist does not set value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating an empty child dropdown, which is filled dynamically according to its parent. When the form is submited, the property `Platform` is always null. Why?

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class SkillsViewModel
{
    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("AddSkill", "AddSkills"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SkillId,
                                new SelectList(ViewBag.SkillsFound, "Id", "SkillName"), "Select skill",
                                new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "SkillSelected()" })

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Platform,
                          new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()),
                          new { @class = "form-control" })

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add skill" class="btn btn-success" />
}
```

And Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSkill(SkillsViewModel model)
{
    // model.Platform is always null
    // to be implemented... 
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is the scrip that populates the dropdown.It works right - adding a list of strings to the dropdown

```
   function SkillSelected() {

    var idSelected = $('#SkillId').val();

    if (idSelected == 0)
    {
        $("#Platform").html("");
    }

    $.post("../GetSkillPlatforms", { skillid: idSelected }, function (data) {
        $("#Platform").html("");
        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
            $("#Platform").append(
                $('<option></option>').val(data.Id).html(data));
        });
    });
}
```

EDIT:

here is the controller that returns the list of strings.

```
public class GetSkillPlatformsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int skillId)
    {
        var Db = new DbContext();

        List<Platform> PlatformsFound = Db.Platforms.Where(pl => pl.PlatformSkill.Id == skillId).ToList();

        List<string> PlatformsNames = new List<string>();

        foreach(Platform pl in PlatformsFound)
        {
            PlatformsNames.Add(pl.PlatformName);
        }

        return Json(PlatformsNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the script where you populate the 2nd dropdownlist

Comment: Well it works right and populates the dropdown with a list of strings, so i think the issue should not be there.

Comment: Of course its there :). Your code for adding the options is wrong - if `data` is a string, then it could not have a property `data.Id` (so each option would have a `null` value). You need to show the controller method that returns the data for generating the options

Comment: I have appended the controller :)

Comment: I see what the trouble ist. It was caused by data not having property called `data.Id`. When i removed `Id` it works fine now.

Comment: Yes, all it needs to be is `$('<option></option>').text(data);`

Comment: And you can simplify the controller to 2 lines of code -  `var PlatformsFound = Db.Platforms.Where(pl => pl.PlatformSkill.Id == skillId).Select(pl => pl.PlatformName); return Json(PlatformsFound);`

Comment: You are right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller method is returning a collection of `string`, and in the script you use of

```
$.each(data, function (i, data) {
    $("#Platform").append($('<option></option>').val(data.Id).html(data));
});
```

is setting the `value` attribute of each option to `null` (`value=""`) because `data` is a `string` and `string` does not contain a property named `Id`.

Change the script to

```
$.each(data, function (i, data) {
    $("#Platform").append($('<option></option>').text(data));
});
```

which omits the `value` attribute, and by default will submit the value of the selected text (or you could use `.append($('<option></option>').val(data).text(data)`)

In addition, you can simplify the controller code to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int skillId)
{
    var Db = new DbContext();
    var model = Db.Platforms.Where(pl => pl.PlatformSkill.Id == skillId).Select(pl => pl.PlatformName);
    return Json(model);
}
```